# MySQL Query Simplication

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I need to get total of each allowances with help of sql query. Now I am using two queries to get results.  But I wanted to get result by running a single query to minimize the time and code. Here is my first query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT master.account_code, master.account_name FROM 0_chart_master AS master WHERE master.account_type IN (60,61,233)
```

From the above query it will show the results of Account code as like below.

```
1700  Payroll Expenses
1710  Rent
1720  Travel Expenses
4000  Miscellaneous
```

And from the each account code I used to query the below query like this.

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM 0_gl_trans WHERE account='1700' AND tran_date >= '2017-10-31' AND tran_date <= '2017-11-30'
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM 0_gl_trans WHERE account='1710' AND tran_date >= '2017-10-31' AND tran_date <= '2017-11-30'
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM 0_gl_trans WHERE account='1720' AND tran_date >= '2017-10-31' AND tran_date <= '2017-11-30'
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM 0_gl_trans WHERE account='4000' AND tran_date >= '2017-10-31' AND tran_date <= '2017-11-30'
```

I need a simplified solution for this difficult situation.

Comment: I think `SELECT SUM(amount), account FROM 0_gl_trans WHERE account in(1700, 1710, 1720, 4000) AND tran_date  between  '2017-10-31' AND '2017-11-30' group by account` would be simpler. You can also join the `master` and get the account type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the totals in an additional column to your first result:

```
SELECT    master.account_code, master.account_name, COALESCE(SUM(trans.amount), 0) AS total 
FROM      0_chart_master AS master
LEFT JOIN 0_gl_trans AS trans 
       ON trans.account = master.account_code
      AND trans.tran_date BETWEEN '2017-10-31' AND '2017-11-30'
WHERE     master.account_type IN (60,61,233)
GROUP BY  master.account_code, master.account_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just filter the accounts and aggregate:

```
SELECT account, sum(amount)
FROM 0_gl_trans 
WHERE account in (
    select account
    from 0_chart_master 
    where account_type IN (60,61,233)
    )
    AND tran_date >= '2017-10-31' 
    AND tran_date <= '2017-11-30'
group by account;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do with a single select  this way

```
  select master.account_code, master.account_name,
    sum( case when account='1700' then amount else 0 end ) tot_1700_payroll_Expenses,
        sum( case when account='1710' then amount else 0 end ) tot_1710_Rent,
        sum( case when account='1720' then amount else 0 end ) tot_1720_Travel_Expenses,
        sum( case when account='4000' then amount else 0 end ) tot_4000_Miscellaneous
  FROM 0_gl_trans WHERE  tran_date >= '2017-10-31' AND tran_date <= '2017-11-30'
  INNER JOIN _chart_master AS master ON master.account_code = 0_gl_trans.account 
          and  master.account_type IN (60,61,233)
  group by master.account_code, master.account_name
```

Comment: conditional aggregation won't work as we dont know which account we'll get

Comment: @GurwinderSingh  correct  .. answer updated with group by

Answer (score 1):

You can use first query as subquery to get relevant `account code` and you can use `Between...AND` for condition on dates.
Try following query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount), 0), 
       account 
FROM 0_gl_trans 
WHERE account in (SELECT DISTINCT master.account_code
                  FROM 0_chart_master AS master 
                  WHERE master.account_type IN (60,61,233)
                  )
AND tran_date between '2017-10-31' AND '2017-11-30' 
group by account;
```

Hope it helps!